# Using git to just monitor changes on a webserver

Tags: linux, git, webserver

I am tasked with monitoring the changes made to the source files of a website.  I am not developing the website, just watching it.  I am a firm believer in using version control, and am a fan of git, but the developer who is actually maintaining the site is not, and I have decided it is better to let him continue to work however he wants (don't ask).  I do not want to have to give him any instructions whatsoever (except possibly telling him that I am adding files or directories that he can ignore).

I consider myself an intermediate-level user of git, so I want to run this by an expert or two.

I am thinking I can install git on the (Linux) server, and then ask for status, and do commits, via SSH.  Will this work without jeopardizing the normal operation of the web server?

Comment: You should be able to remote into the remote server using SSH and use Git remotely that way...is this a development server or a production server? If you're both doing development, then neither of you should actually be developing on a production server, only deploying code to it when it's ready to be deployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using Git on a server should not interfere with the normal operation of the server (as mentioned in the comments, doing this on a production server is dodgy but I'll leave that to one side.)

Note that using Git normally will create a `.git` directory at the root of whatever you're tracking. If that is your web server root directory, you might want to consider whether this is a risk as far as external access to the contents of the `.git` directory (depending on your server setup, this may or may not be a concern).

If you want to create the `.git` directory somewhere else outside your working tree, see the `GIT_DIR` environment variable.

Comment: I didn't know you could put the .git directory somewhere else, so that is extremely useful.  As for the dodginess, well, that is why I am monitoring the situation and not wanting to make it any worse.